# Recreate a GUI for an application

Tags: user-interface

im new here, lately i've tried to find a way to recreate a GUI for an application and still maintain his functionality.

Let's take SnapChat as example, i would redesing the application GUI but without editing that part of code that makes the application function.Im sorry if im not giving very specific explanations but i really don't know how to say it. Im really clueless on how to do so, and even if is possible in in the first place.

If someone could help me out it would be really apreaciate

So far i haven't tried anything bheside searching something online.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you want to make a 'frontend' that looks like Snapchat and have it functioning like the real site. You will need to have a backend will all the features of Snapchat. Most websites on the internet have two parts to them - frontend and the backend. And most sites won't allow you to access their backend from other frontend for security reasons.
I personally don't use that site so I don't know about its features, but assuming it's a chat platform you will need user authentication and some way to store your messages.
You should start out with React or Vue.js, and work your way up to responsive sites like Snapchat.
A quick and easy solution would be to create an extension that changes the styling once the site loads on your machine so you don't have to code your own front-end.